# How to check the content of each .txt file in a folder with Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io, io

I have a folder that contains files. I was wondering how I can chech every .txt file in the folder if it contains the word "BREAK". I know it must be very easy but I kinda miss the way of getting it done.

This is what I've tried so far

```
Dir.glob('/path/to/dir/*.txt') do |txt_file|
  # And here I need a method that opens the 'txt_file'
  # and checks if it contains "BREAK"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below would return an `array` of files containing "BREAK"

```
files = Dir.glob('/path/to/dir/*.txt').select do |txt_file|
  File.read(txt_file).include? "BREAK"
end
```